# Manipulate function with variable number of controls

Tags: r

My objective is to have a function that can be called with an array of *n* datasets. This function will call [`manipulate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/manipulate/versions/1.0.1/topics/manipulate-package) and create a plot with a control box. This box will have as many checkboxes as there are datasets (i.e. *n*). Each checkbox will allow to show/hide the corresponding dataset on the plot.

For the purpose of keeping it simple, I will assume each dataset is a simple string instead.

---

`manipulate` works fine when the controls are known. Here, for a single control:

```
manipulate(plot(0,0,main=b), b=checkbox(TRUE, 'bool'))
```

[image]

However, in my case I need a variable number of controls. I'm able to create a list of controls like so:

```
dataList = c('a', 'b', 'c')
ctrls = list()
for(data in dataList) {
  ctrls[[data]] = checkbox(TRUE, data)
}

manipulate(plot(0,0), ctrls)
```

[image]

Now let's see a minimal use case : a function that will create a plot. Its title will be the concatenation of all dataset names which have the value `TRUE`.

My initial idea was to pass the list of controls to the function, so I can access each control there.

```
foo <- function(dataList, ctrls) {
  print(dataList)
  title = ''
  for(data in dataList) {
    if (ctrls[[data]]) {                 # this fails
      title=cat(title, data)
    }
  }
  plot(0,0,main=title)
}

manipulate(foo(dataList, ctrls), ctrls)
```

The above fails because `ctrls[[data]]` is not the value of the control.

**Is there a way to access the current value of a control when it's given to `manipulate` inside a list?**

Comment: It wouldn't be `if (ctrls[[datalist]][data]` for value of datalist at count data?

Comment: No, I'm affraid that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling around I found that I could utilize the [`get`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/get) function to retrieve the variables' values from the scope before calling `foo`.

1. Firstly, I prepare the list of controls

   ```
   series = list('a', 'b', 'c')
   controls = list()
   for(data in series) {
     controls[[data]] = checkbox(TRUE, data)
   }
   ```
2. Then we have the callback function which takes a list as argument

   ```
   foo <- function(data, bools) {
     t=""
     for(i in seq_along(data)) {
       if(bools[[i]]) t = c(t, data[[i]])
     }
     plot(0,0,main=t)
   }
   ```
3. Finally there's the call to `manipulate`. Notice I'm mapping the list of series names with their corresponding checkbox's state (`TRUE` or `FALSE`).

   ```
   manipulate(
     foo(lapply(series, function(e) get(e))), 
     controls
   )
   ```

[image]